# Google script code not working in other sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

this is the code that i am currently running in mainWsName sheet. It is basically a dependent dropdown list.
I also want this same script/code to work in another sheet. I tried to change all the variables in to the new sheet. But then the script does only work in one of the sheets. I want it to work in both the sheets.
[image]

```js
var mainWsName = "Inkoop";
var sittardWsName = "Sittard";
var merkColumn = 4;
var modelColumn = 5;
var categorieColumn = 6;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wsSittard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sittardWsName);
var arraySittard = wsSittard.getRange(2,1,wsSittard.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();


function categorie(){
}

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getSheetName()

  if(wsName == mainWsName && c == merkColumn && r > 1){
      if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r ,categorieColumn).clearContent();
    } else{
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      var filterarraySittard = arraySittard.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filterarraySittard.map(function(o){ return o[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply, cell);
    }
  }
} // end onEdit


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's only working in one sheet is because you are telling the program to only work in a single sheet.

If you look on your `onEdit(e)` function there is only one sheet that you are modifying, `ws`. Therefore you need to change the variable naming to be able to modify both sheets:

#### Modified Script

Basically instead of statically getting the sheet to be modify (`ws`) retrieve it from the [`onEdit` event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

```
var mainWsNames = ["Inkoop", "Verkoop"]; // Changed to an array of names to modify
var sittardWsName = "Sittard";
var merkColumn = 4;
var modelColumn = 5;
var categorieColumn = 6;


var wsSittard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sittardWsName);
var arraySittard = wsSittard.getRange(2,1,wsSittard.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();


function categorie(){
}

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var ws = activeCell.getSheet();
  var wsName = ws.getSheetName();

// Check if the name of the worksheet is in the array previously defined with indexOf
  if(mainWsName.indexOf(wsName) != -1 && c == merkColumn && r > 1){
      if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r ,categorieColumn).clearContent();
    } else{
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      var filterarraySittard = arraySittard.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filterarraySittard.map(function(o){ return o[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply, cell);
    }
  }
} // end onEdit


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```js
var mainWsName = "Inkoop";
var wsVerkoop = "Verkoop"
var sittardWsName = "Sittard";
var merkColumn = 4;
var modelColumn = 5;
var categorieColumn = 6;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainWsName);
var wVerkoop = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsVerkoop);
var wsSittard = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sittardWsName);
var arraySittard = wsSittard.getRange(2,1,wsSittard.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();


function categorie(){
}

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getSheetName()

  if(wsName == mainWsName && c == merkColumn && r > 1){
      if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      ws.getRange(r ,categorieColumn).clearContent();
    } else{
      ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      var filterarraySittard = arraySittard.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filterarraySittard.map(function(o){ return o[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(r ,modelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply, cell);
    }
  }
  if(wsName == wsVerkoop && c == merkColumn && r > 1){
      if(val === ""){
      wVerkoop.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      wVerkoop.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearDataValidations();
      wVerkoop.getRange(r ,categorieColumn).clearContent();
    } else{
      wVerkoop.getRange(r ,modelColumn).clearContent();
      var filterarraySittard = arraySittard.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
      var listToApply = filterarraySittard.map(function(o){ return o[1]});
      var cell = wVerkoop.getRange(r ,modelColumn);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply, cell);
    }
  }  
} // end onEdit


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice that you briefly describe the changes that you made